# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'addEventListener') in javaScript

Tags: javascript, html, thymeleaf

> I am using javaScript to handle play and pause button when user click
> on play pause button, but it is not working in my case it throw
> following error in my console when click on play buttonUncaught TypeError: Cannot read

```
properties of null (reading 'addEventListener')
    at myMusic.js:46:12
```

> Here is my handle play pause function

```
let audioElement = new Audio('song/Si Tu Te Vas.mp3');
let masterPlay = document.getElementById('masterPlay');
/**Handle play pause click*/
masterPlay.addEventListener('click', () => {
    if (audioElement.pause() || audioElement.currentTime <= 0) {
        audioElement.play();
        masterPlay.classList.remove('fa-play-circle');
        masterPlay.classList.add('fa-pause-circle');
        gif.style.opacity = 1;
    } else {
        audioElement.pause();
        masterPlay.classList.remove('fa-pause-circle');
        masterPlay.classList.add('fa-play-circle');
        gif.style.opacity = 0;
    }
})
```

> Mymusic.html

```
<script type="text/javascript" th:src="@{/js/myMusic.js}"></script>
<div class="icons">
        <!--Font awsome icon -->
        <i class="fas fa-3x fa-backward" id="previous"></i>
        <i class="far fa-3x fa-play-circle" id="masterPlay"></i>
        <i class="fas fa-3x fa-forward" id="next"></i>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Place the `<script>` tag after the `<div class="icons">`

Scripts cannot get DOM content loaded after it

Or you could wrap your javascript in:

```js
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
   // Your code here
})
```

To wait for the DOM content all loaded in before the script :)

Comment: This question gets asked several times a day. On StackOverflow, we don't want many answers to many questions which all solve the same problem; so for very common problems like this please instead of answering check for duplicates, and if you find one, vote to close as duplicate of that question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14028959/why-does-jquery-or-a-dom-method-such-as-getelementbyid-not-find-the-element

Comment: That made the community seems to be unfriendly

Comment: I am sorry you feel treated in an unfriendly manner; that was not my intention at all. I've tried to explain the reasoning and kindly asked you to proceed differently on these types of questions in the future.